# Is $\mathbb{F}_p$ flat over $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$ ($N\geq 5$, not divisible by $p$)?

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness

I am trying to understand the paper "Generators and relations of the graded algebra
of modular forms", N. Rustom. It is being claimed that for an integer $N\geq 5$ and a prime $p$ not dividing $N$, $\mathbb{F}_p$ is flat over $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$. In what sense should this be understood? I think that for a PID (such as $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$) the quotient by a maximal ideal can not be a flat module.

Comment: You’re right. For integral domains being flat implies being torsion-free. Something is odd here.

Comment: You can exhibit an explicit failure of flatness by noting that the multiplication by $p$ : $\mathbb Z[1/N]\to \mathbb Z[1/N]$ is injective but its tensor with $\mathbb F_p$ is not. As pointed out earlier, more generally, over an integral domain, any flat module is torsion free. I don't know another sense of "flat"